# Spring JPA Query. Join Table with @OneToMany properties

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have the following two Models:

```
class Game {

    private long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Team> teams;
    ...
}

class Team {
    private long id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> members;
    ...
}
```

The user model holds a `String username`.
Now I want to create a query that results in the Team when I pass the Game and username as parameters:

```
public interface TeamRepository extends Repository<Team, Long> {
    @Query("select t from Game g join Team t where g = :game and :username member of t.members")
    Team findTeamByUserInGame(Game game, String username);
}
```

But I can't figure out how to join the Game table with the Team table and then how to check if username is in members. Any help?

Comment: You tagged the question with spring-data-jpa and spring-data-jdbc. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Game g join g.teams t where g = :game and exists (select m from g.teams join t.members m where m = :user)")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of join, you can query for g.teams.members.username=:username

```
public interface TeamRepository extends Repository<Team, Long> {
    @Query("select g from Game g where g = :game and g.teams.members.username=:username")
    Team findTeamByUserInGame(Game game, String username);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Game g join Team t` instead of `Game g`? Because there isn't a variable "t". And g.teams.username doesn't exist as well.

Comment: You do not need to add JOIN. JPA will automatically join.   and regarding variable, it will be g.teams.members.username

Comment: My IDE shows two syntax errors: "Cannot resolve symbol t" and "Cannot resolve symbol "members".

Comment: Another small mistake. your alias to Game is g. So, you should select g i.e. select g from Game g where g = :game and g.teams.members.username=:username